# How to change value of button in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

```
{{ Form::open(array('' => 'menu/profile', 'files' => true)) }}
{{ Form::file('image') }}

{{ Form::submit('Save changes') }}
{{ Form::close() }}

{{ Form::file('image') }}
```

This gives me button with value=browse.
Can i change that to for example upload, and also near that button is "no file selected". 
Can i hide that somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not larval MVC issue.

but yes you can fix this issue using below
Possible Solutions:

hack

```
input[type='file'] {
  opacity:0    
}
```

or

set width / height

```
input[type="file"]{
    opacity:0;
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
}
```

or 
just play with width

```
input[type='file'] {
  width: 95px;
 }
```

Tested on Chrome 20, Safari 5.1.7 and IE 9.

or 
Make it transparent

```
input[type='file'] {
  color: transparent;
}

<input type='file'/>
```

example
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjCeF/v)

See link :

http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/

Answer (score 0):

This is not laravel related, but browser specific. it will say "browse" in IE and FireFox, but "choose file" in Chrome.

There are some workarounds for it, but its better to not change browser defaults. However if you still want to change the file input check [here](http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/)